Read OTLP from a file instead of http/grpc
There are various exporters that can write JSON or proto OTLP to a file, e.g. s3-exporter and file exporter but what do I do with these files?
Say I want to ingest them into clickhouse using the clickhouse exporter,  I could start up a pipeline with OTLP receiver and write a small script to POST the proto blobs to the HTTP endpoint but that feels overly convoluted. Is there some receiver example somewhere that reads OTLP/proto from disk?
I tried using file exporter and can make sense of the generated files, but it's not clear how to get them back into a pipeline.

There is otlpjsonfilereceiver which is designed to read the   OTLP json serialized data from the file back to pipeline. This is like a complementary counter part to the file exporter that writes. And similarly, there is s3receiver to retrieve the trace data previously written by s3 exporter (currently in development phase).
